# Windows 7 booting fails

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu, boot

I have a Windows 7 PC. Some days ago it fails to boot. When the system is switched on, the motherboard screens appears first, then the 'Starting Windows' screens and then a black screen with busy icon appears. This screen continues for a certain time and the system restarts again.

So I turned off my system forcibly and started it again. Then the startup repair option came and I performed it. Then the booting problem was solved.

After 2 days from that, I installed Ubuntu 13.10 along side windows. The installation was successful and I was able to boot both OS at any time. But today Windows start to show the same old problem again. I tried boot repair from Ubuntu, but nothing happened. So I forcibly turned off my system and the Safe Mode options came at next Startup for Windows. I selected safe mode, but here too the booting is failing.

Why Windows behaves like this ? How can I solve this issue permanently ?

---

I think startup repair will solve the issue. Is there any way to do the startup repair before or while windows boot ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself. I just created a Windows 7 Repair Disc and with it I performed a Startup Repair. Now the problem is solved and Windows 7 is booting fine.

Answer (score -1):

(Opinion)

Is your PC a laptop or a Tower (Desktop)?

If its a laptop I would recommend backup everything and doing a system reset when you need to go into and look up you laptop manufacturer and found out how to restore to factory settings. (example if you have a Dell : http://en.kioskea.net/faq/4189-dell-laptops-restore-factory-settings) It really depends on your laptop.

If its a Desktop then again back up everything and just re-install windows or go fully with Ubuntu.

I know its a lot of work but its the best way to fix a problem like this.

Comment: My PC is a tower. Your answer is the last option for me. Let me wait for other good answers.

Comment: That is perfectly fine. Though just a little recommendation to put some key components on your original post. (example. motherboard etc.)